# Trouble to predict the effect of pressure and temperature for a reaction in equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium

I have trouble to predict the effect of decreasing pressure and increasing temperature on the reaction $\ce{N2 + 2O2 <=> 2NO2}$. 
Increasing temperature caused this reaction to shift in the forward direction and decreasing pressure brought no change. 
I know increasing temperature favour endothermic reaction and decreasing temperature favour exothermic reaction. I also know on increasing pressure the system will shift to the direction where less moles are present.
 Please tell me how to use this information to predict the effect for increasing temperature and decreasing pressure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I posted this question I had no idea how changing each factor bring change in equilibrium. Then I bombarded my brain with everything I know about equilibrium and I found a fairly easy way to understand this.

**Change in concentration**

Imagine two vessels A and B connected to each other through a thin hollow pipe through the middle of the vessel. Let vessel A be reactant and vessel B be product. The vessels are filled with water a little above the pipe. If I add water to vessel A  water flow from A to B. Thus increasing concentrated of A caused the water in vessel A to flow to B; which in other words is the forward reaction.

**Change in temperature**

Think of a reaction which is in equilibrium.

1)Decreasing the temperature of reaction in equilibrium.

We know that decreasing the temperature favour exothermic reaction
 and exothermic reaction are favoured by low temperature. Exothermic mean giving out heat which remove the deficiency of temperature to bring it back to normal in equilibrium.

2) Increasing the the temperature of reaction in equilibrium

We also know that increasing the temperature favour endothermic reaction or endothermic reaction are favoured by high temperature. Endothermic means to absorb heat energy which causes the excess heat energy ( from high temperature) to bring it back to normal in equilibrium

**Effect of pressure**

Changing pressure play a significant role in gaseous reaction which are accompanied by change in moles. On increasing pressure of the system equilibrium will shift to the direction where number of moles decrease or where pressure decrease (because pressure is directly proportional to the number of moles). If pressure on the system is increased equilibrium shift in the direction in which decrease in number of moles take place.

This is the second time I answered on stack exchange so please let me know my mistake if any. If I had known how to create the diagrams I usually find in other answers I would have added them.